# jQuery animate lagging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jQuery code that slide an "em" tag up, on hover, and down on blur:

```
$(".entries a").hover(
  function () {
   $(this).find("em").animate( { height:"100%"}, 500 )
   
  }, 
  function () {
  $(this).find("em").animate( { height:"0%"}, 500 )
  }
);
```

html code

```
<div class="entries">
<a href="http://www.website.com"> 
<em>Description</em> 
<img src="thumb.jpg"/> 
</a>
<a href="http://www.website.com"> 
<em>Description</em> 
<img src="thumb.jpg"/> 
</a> 
<a href="http://www.website.com"> 
<em>Description</em> 
<img src="thumb.jpg"/> 
</a> 
</div>
```

When I move my mouse outside the a tag, the em tag jump down a few pixels down and then begin to slide. This creates sort of a lagging effect.

Is there a better way to write this?

Like using a var to cache the `$(this).find("em")`?

Any tips for performance and code style would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this, I think it is the effect that you're going for, and it uses smoother transitions.

```
$(".entries a").hover(
  function () {
   $(this).find("em").slideDown(500);
  }, 
  function () {
  $(this).find("em").slideUp(500);
  }
);
```

**Edit**:
if you want something really efficient, you may want to avoid jQuery for the selection and just use `$(this.childNodes[1])` to select it.
`[1]` is because whitespace is element 0

Comment: Thanks, works better. How can I cache the $(this).find("em") in a var, and use it in the code?

Comment: Do you know how much faster it is? Can I really notice a difference? Sorry to ask this again, but I'd really like to know, how can I cache the $(this).find("em") in a var, and use it in the code?

Comment: There isn't really an easy way to cache it that I can see because you are applying a single function to several elements, you would need an array, which would require keeping an index for each element, and then its back to square one

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your specific issue, but I recommend you look into the JQuery UI.  It has animation effects similar to what you've attempted here.